# How to find ActiveRecord object that has a unique column values compared to other closeby objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, activerecord

I have a boolean column called `active` in a table called `user`.

I'm trying to find `users` where the `user` before and after the `current_user` do not have the same value in column `active`.

```rb
def has_unique_active_value
  user_ids_to_check = [self.id + 1, self.id - 1] # user.id before and after current_user
  if User.where(id: user_ids_to_check, active: self.active).present?
    return nil
  else
    return self
  end
end

current_user = User.all.first.has_unique_active_value
```

The above should return a `user` if the `active` column value is different to the `user` before and after. if not, it should return `nil`

Would there be an easier or better practice to use in order to get the outcome I'm after?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: `[self.id + 1, self.id - 1]`, ids might not always follow an incremental order.

Comment: What do you mean with "if the active column value is _unique_ to the user"?

Comment: @SebastianPalma postgreSQL in prod. SQLite3 in Dev. And "unique" was a typo, should be "different" to the user before and after.

Comment: @SebastianPalma instead of [self.id + 1, self.id - 1] is there a function like self.created_at.next and self.created_at.previous ?

Comment: It should return "a" (one) user matching the criteria? or "the" user (self)?

Comment: @SebastianPalma in this case, self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incrementing/Decrementing self.id may not be correct since that user may no longer exist. It would be better to find the next/previous ids. You can find the **previous record** by **selecting the maximum id smaller than self.id**. Similarly, you can find the **next record** by selecting the **minimum id larger than self.id**.

```
def has_unique_active_value
  user_ids_to_check = [User.where("id < ?", self.id).maximum(:id), User.where("id > ?", self.id).minimum(:id)]
  User.where(id: user_ids_to_check, active: self.active).present? ? nil : self
end

current_user = User.all.first.has_unique_active_value
```

Comment: Doing three queries when you can do just one, is, amazing.

Comment: Thanks, so is writing database specific queries as you did in your deleted answer.

Comment: If you can think of a better solution feel free to post or help me improve my answer. Your sarcasm isn't helping anyone here.

Comment: `User.exists?([
    '(id = IFNULL((SELECT MIN(id) FROM users WHERE id > :id), 0) OR
      id = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(id) FROM users WHERE id < :id), 0)) AND active = :active',
    id: id,
    active: active
  ])`, that's all.